# Disregard an item in a Loop with a specific property

Tags: javascript

I have this loop right here:

```
function sendBackOne() {
    var selected = paper.project.selectedItems;
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        console.log(selected[i].name);
    }
```

where ***selected*** is an array with items that i iterate over.

One of the items has a ''name'' property set to ''something''. **I don't want to go over that element in my loop,i need to disregard it.**

How would i go about doing that?

The best way i can figure is writing an IF/ELSE statement in the loop to check the name and if it's not ''something'' i do what i need to do.

Is this the best way?

Comment: Other than filtering the array before doing your `for` loop, I believe this will be the *only* way. `if (selected[i].name === 'something') { continue; }`

Comment: If it's just one item with a specific value, you can also remove that item from the array easily even before you run your for loop.

Comment: Any other solution would require filtering the collection first, which would mean looping over the collection just to remove an item and then looping over it again to actually do whatever you want. It would be much better in terms of performance to just loop once and have a condition in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. You can also use a [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statement like this

```
var selected = paper.project.selectedItems;
for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    if (selected[i].name === "something") continue;
    ... // Whatever you wanted to do, goes here
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to type if (selected[i].name != "something") continue;    since i need to disregard all elements with "something" as the name propery.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Nope :) If the `name` is something`, body of the loop will be skipped by `continue` :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
if (selected[i].name == "something")
    continue;
```

Use `continue` to head to the next iteration.